# Dreamhost: MySQL FOREIGN KEY

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, dreamhost

I'm having an issue with foreign keys on Dreamhost's MySQL. Every time I try to add foreign key to a table I get the error "cannot add foreign key constraint." The syntax I used is ALTER TABLE (table_name) ADD FOREIGN KEY(key_name) REFERENCES another_table(another column). I also checked that both tables used the innodb storage engine. Each column was only ints. I'm not sure if this issue is directly related to the hosting provider or not. The MySQL version is 5.6.25-log. I can't run the SHOW ENGINE STATUS\G and I can't do any operations that check the PROCESSLIST.

Comment: Can you show the table definitions?

Comment: What is the DDL statement for that in MySQL? DESCRIBE table_name?

Answer (score 0):

Dreamhost apparently has the `REFERENCES` command disabled (to protect other databases on the shared hosting environment?). Therefore FK checks are not possible.

See: [MySQL limitations due to shared hosting](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000263911-MySQL-limitations-due-to-shared-hosting) at Dreamhost